# Web Sockets with Spring and HTML5

Tags: html, spring, websocket

I want to send messages from a server to connected clients. I’ve tries to do this by using web sockets. But it isn’t working…

Javascript Code within my HTML view:

```
socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/messages');
socket.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e);
 }
```

Spring configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@Import(WebSocketAutoConfiguration.class)
public class WebSocketConfiguration extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(final MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/messages");
    }
}
```

Service class to send messages:

```
@Service
public class MessageSender {

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;

    public void sendMessage(final String message) {
        this.messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/", message);
    }
}
```

Actually the client receives nothing.
What destination must be set to send a message to the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your configuration, you are using STOMP over WebSocket
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-enable

The proper use would be:

```
var socket = new WebSocket("/spring-websocket-portfolio/portfolio");
var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
})
```

Open Dev console, STOMP prints good logs :)